# AS3/CS6: Tweening array of movieclips: they all just stop except 1

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, tween

Hey so I'm trying to apply tweens to each item in an array (this is all just an experiment... I'm trying to learn more about tweens). Here's my code:

```
import flash.events.Event
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.motion.Color; 

var bubbles:Array = [];
var numBubbles:int=55;

for (var i:Number=0; i<=numBubbles-1;i++){
    bubbles.push(new bubble());
    stage.addChild(bubbles[i]);
    startMotion(bubbles[i]);
}

function startMotion( TheBubble:bubble ){
    var tweenY:Tween = new Tween(TheBubble, "y", Regular.easeIn, TheBubble.y, -5, 3, true);
}
```

I'm having is that most of the time, the tweens start to play but then all the tweens stop except on one of the bubbles.

Sometimes they finish and a finish is more likely when numBubbles is set to a low number like 5 to 10. Could this be a tween limit problem? I didn't figure that to be likely.

The bubble that keeps going isn't the first bubble of the array or the last. I'm still trying to narrow down which one it is but I've figured that much by coloring the first and last.
Edit: It seems to be (somewhat) random. Sometimes the colored one makes it - most of the time it's one of the others.

Oh, and here's the bubble class:

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.easing.*;

    public class bubble extends MovieClip{
        var bubbleSize:int;
        public function bubble(){
            this.bubbleSize=Math.ceil(Math.random()*15)+15;
            this.width=bubbleSize;
            this.height=bubbleSize;
            this.x = Math.random()*(550-bubbleSize);
            this.y = 400+Math.random()*400;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help or insight!

Comment: It doesn't look like an issue with your instantiation.  Perhaps your tween class is having issues tracking the items properly.  Have you tried TweenLite instead?  I think you'll enjoy it.  (http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a race condition going on, try animating *after* they have for sure been added to the stage:

```
...
for (var i:Number=0; i<=numBubbles-1;i++){
    bubbles.push(new bubble());
    bubbles[i].addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, startMotion);
    stage.addChild(bubbles[i]);
}

function startMotion( evt:Event ){
    var TheBubble:bubble = bubble(evt.target);
    var tweenY:Tween = new Tween(TheBubble, "y", Regular.easeIn, TheBubble.y, -5, 3, true);
}
```

Also, since you are exploring the world of Tweens in Flash, I strongly recommend checking out the [Tween Lite / Tween Max](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) library.

Comment: Hello, thanks fro the reply. That was a good thought and at first I thought it fixed it because it worked like 4 times in a row but then the problem came back. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed by someone at Adobe forum: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1260275

We should use this code instead:

```
import flash.events.Event

import fl.transitions.TweenEvent

import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import flash.utils.Dictionary;

import flash.display.MovieClip;

import fl.transitions.Tween;

import fl.transitions.easing.*;

import fl.motion.Color;



var bubbles:Array = [ ];

var numBubbles:int=55;

var tweenY:Tween;

var tweenA:Array = [];



for (var i:Number=0; i<=numBubbles-1;i++){

    bubbles.push(new bubble());

    stage.addChild(bubbles[i]);

    startMotion(bubbles[i]);

}



function startMotion( TheBubble:bubble ){

    tweenY = new Tween(TheBubble, "y", Regular.easeIn, TheBubble.y, -5, 3, true);

tweenA.push(tweenY);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're main code is in a timeline frame as opposed to an .as file it might be getting triggered over and over by the looping 'playhead'. Add a 'stop()' early on and that might fix things (?)
Either that or link your Flash file to an external Document.as Class and put your main code in there.